# RSS feed from Facebook posts

Tags: facebook, rss, feedly

I would like to subscribe to some user (not me) Facebook posts via RSS feed. I heard Facebook disabled native RSS feed feature some years ago.
Is there a way to get RSS feed from Facebook posts of some user?

I heard Zapier supports this only for your own Facebook pages - I need this not for my user.
Fetchrss says "Facebook privacy policies ***does not allow*** us to generate RSS for most ***user profiles***" - I need this for user profile.

Comment: No, there is no RSS feed for that. Any app that wants to create one itself by reading the user’s posts via API, would need that user’s explicit permission to do so first.

Comment: @04FS Thanks. Any official docs about that?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v4.0/user/feed#read

Comment: @04FS Thank you very much. Could you please create an answer with this info so that I can select it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn’t a build-in function for this. (RSS feeds used to be a thing for pages, but never for user profiles.)

---

Any app that wants to create such a feed itself by reading the user’s posts via API, would need that user’s explicit permission to do so first.

The basic permission needed is mentioned in the documentation under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v4.0/user/feed#read